# Html output takes too long to load

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, r-markdown, knitr

I have this html knit output from Rmarkdown but since it is pretty heavy (it is an online guide), the page takes too long to show up when opening the link. I tried to divide the rmd file into distinct rms sub files as below shown but I still can't get the result. Thank you

````
title: "my_file"
author: "me"
date: "26/02/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float:
      collapsed: yes
      smooth_scroll: yes
  word_document: default
---


```{r child = 'child0.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child2.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child3.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'child4.Rmd'}
```
````

Comment: I think you need to give more details:  how long does it take?  How big are the files?  But in general, you could to break up the input into separate source files that produced separate output files too, not just one big .html output, and that should allow faster loading of each of them.  The `blogdown` package supports this.

Comment: it takes about 30/40 seconds,  17,7 MB the whole html output. How can I implement blogdown in my rmd? Sorry but I am very new to this

Comment: I'll add an answer giving some details.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to speed things up is to break up your web site into multiple pages.  You can use the `blogdown` package to support this, but for a first try, it's even easier to use an RStudio site generator.  Here are the steps:

1. Create a new RStudio project; choose "Simple R Markdown website" for the type of project.  This automatically creates three files, `_site.yml`, `about.Rmd`, `index.Rmd`.
2. Decide how you want to break up the files into separate pages, and create `.Rmd` files for each one.  The headers should be similar to the ones in `about.Rmd` and `index.Rmd`, and you
   should add lines to `_site.yml` for each page.
3. Click on "Build website" in the Build pane (usually top right in RStudio).  This will process all of the files and open the website at the index page.

The HTML files will be stored in the `_site` folder within your project; you can copy them from there to your web server.